# Получение названия столбцов в DataFrame, в которых есть пустые значения.(Python)

Tags: python, dataframe

Есть загруженный из файла DataFrame размерность (1460, 81). В некоторых столбцах есть пустые значения.
Поставлена задача:
Используя соответствующий встроенный метод, дропните, т. е. удалите из нашей таблички все столбцы, у которых количество пропущенных значений больше 200.
Найдите все такие столбцы (метод .isna() + подвыборка с условием).
Определите их названия.
Дропните их (используйте метод .drop(имена столбцов)).
Проверяю на наличие пустых:

```
print(data.isna().sum())
```

Есть такие:

```
Id                 0
MSSubClass         0
MSZoning           0
LotFrontage      259
LotArea            0
                ... 
MoSold             0
YrSold             0
SaleType           0
SaleCondition      0
SalePrice          0
Length: 81, dtype: int64
```

Делаю маску:

```
mask = data.isna().sum() > 200
```

Получаю одномерный массив:

```
Id               False
MSSubClass       False
MSZoning         False
LotFrontage       True
LotArea          False
                 ...  
MoSold           False
YrSold           False
SaleType         False
SaleCondition    False
SalePrice        False
Length: 81, dtype: bool
```

В индексах название столбцов, как вытащить эти названия у которых значения True. Или можно пойти другим путем?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ:

```
mask = data.isna().sum() > 200
data.columns[mask]
```